# AJAX tabs with inputs and forms .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Im new to AJAX and .Net Core. I have a tab page in my view (this is supposed to be a ForgotMyPassword Page)

```
<div id="tab1">
        <input id="UserKeyInput" type="text" autofocus placeholder="UserKey">
        <button id="btnn">Next</button>

</div>
<div id="tab2"> <!-IF VALIDATION=TRUE SWITCH TO THIS TAB-->
        <input id="UserKeyInput" type="text" autofocus placeholder="newpassword">
        <button id="btnn">done</button>

</div>
```

in JS i have

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $("#btnn").click(function () {
        alert("ss");
        var UserKey;
        UserKey = $("#UserKeyInput").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ValidateUser")',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

How could I have AJAX change the tab if the validation was successful? Should I have one single function that switches tabs and performs actions or should i have a function for each tab?
the other thing is what would happen if the user refreshed the page after `ValidateUser` is done and we are on the second tab page?(would it show the `tab1` or `tab2`)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have same id in same view.

View

```
<div id="tab1">
        <input id="UserKeyInput1" type="text" autofocus placeholder="UserKey">
        <button id="btnn1">Next</button>

</div>
<div id="tab2" style="display: none;"> <!-IF VALIDATION=TRUE SWITCH TO THIS TAB-->
        <input id="UserKeyInput2" type="text" autofocus placeholder="newpassword">
        <button id="btnn2">done</button>

</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
   $("#btnn1").click(function () {
      var UserKey = $("#UserKeyInput1").val();
      $.post('@Url.Action("ValidateUser")', { userkey: UserKey }).done(function (e) {
         if (e.success === false)
         {
             return false;
         }
         $("#tab1").hide();
         $("#tab2").show();
      });
   });
</script>
```